# How do I convert CakePHP json to use with JS JIT SpaceTree?

Tags: javascript, json, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP to query my database table 'Task' that includes project_id, id, parent_id, title, description.  My controller code handles the query like so:

```
$query= $this->Task->find('threaded', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Task.project_id'  => 83,
                ), 
                'fields' => array(
                    'Task.id',
                    'Task.title',
                    'Task.parent_id',

                )
        ));
//Pass the result to the view
$this->set('query', $query);
```

Then in my view, if I decode the json with the following:

```
<?php echo json_encode($simple); ?>
```

I get the following json structure:

```
[
{
    "Task": {
        "id": "475",
        "title": "Have a Picnic",
        "parent_id": "0"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "Task": {
                "id": "476",
                "title": "Drive/Hike to Moutains",
                "parent_id": "475"
            },
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

]

*(I used [this tool](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/gfx/demos/beautify.html) in to beautify it, the output is of course a continuous string)*

But JS JIT SpaceTree requires the following structure:

```
    {
  "id": "aUniqueIdentifier",
  "name": "usually a nodes name",
  "data": [
      {key:"some key",       value: "some value"},
    {key:"some other key", value: "some other value"}
  ],
  children: [/* other nodes or empty */]
}
```

And I have no idea how to either adjust the output, or change my query to return the correct structure.  Also, I've tried both 'threaded' and 'list' find() types and get the same structure.  Any help is greatly appreiciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply iterate over the results and map the data into your desired structure, that's a pretty basic task. You could do that in the controller, in the view (maybe using a helper), or even in the model using a custom find method.

Here's a simple example. I don't know what `data` is good for, also there are no further fields in your result, so I've left that part.

```
function mapThreaded($source, &$target)
{
    foreach($source as $item)
    {
        $node = array
        (
            'id' => $item['Task']['id'],
            'name' => $item['Task']['title'],
            'children' => array()
        );

        if(count($item['children']))
        {
            mapThreaded($item['children'], $node['children']);
        }

        $target[] = $node;
    }
}

$tasks = $this->Task->find('threaded', array(...));

$tree = array();
mapThreaded($tasks, $tree);

pr($tree);
pr(json_encode($tree, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)); // pretty print requires PHP >= 5.4.0
```

It should result in a JSON structure like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "475",
        "name": "Have a Picnic",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "476",
                "name": "Drive/Hike to Moutains",
                "children": [

                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In case Spacetree supports only a single root elment, simply use `current($tree)` or in JavaScript pass the first array entry to Spacetree.

Comment: Thank you ndm! You've just ended hours of furstration and confusion!! The only thing that needs changing (for my setup) is that calling this method in the cotroller requires: $this->mapThreaded($tasks, $tree);